# Capture chrome tab without browse action

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, chromium

I have a simple method which captures current tab, and it works only when this method triggered by click on extension button (i.e. browserAction).

But when I use this method in setTimeout event it fails with following error:

```
Unchecked runtime.lastError while running tabCapture.capture: Extension has not been invoked for the current page (see activeTab permission). Chrome pages cannot be captured.
```

My simple capture method is:

```
function captureTab() {
    var constraints = ...
    chrome.tabCapture.capture(constraints, function (stream) {
        if (!stream) {
            console.error("couldn't record tab");
            return;
        }
        // recording succeeded
    });
}
```

And it works when it triggered as follows:

```
chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(function () {
    chrome.tabs.getSelected(null, function (tab) {
        captureTab();
    });
});
```

But **doesn't** work when it triggered as follows:

```
setTimeout(function () {
    chrome.tabs.getSelected(1, function (tab) {
        captureTab();            
    });
}, 1 * 30 * 1000);
```

**Important note:** My extension isn't a public extension and it runs only on my browser so I can add any command line switch on start (in order to disable this limitation), if needed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Please be aware [chrome.tabCapture.capture](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tabCapture#method-capture) can only be started on the currently active tab after the extension has been invoked.

> Captures the visible area of the currently active tab. Capture can only be started on the currently active tab after the extension has been invoked.

And when you declare [activeTab](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/activeTab) permissions, only the following user gestures enable it

> - Executing a browser action
> - Executing a page action
> - Executing a context menu item
> - Executing a keyboard shortcut from the commands API
> - Accepting a suggestion from the omnibox API

So when you are using `setTimeOut`, you can not ensure current tab is active.

Comment: You right. There is no any way to do that. However, since in my case I start chrome programmatically from external app, I set a listener in extension to keyboard shortcut (using commands API) and then from my external app I trigger this keyboard shortcut. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 3):

I know this is weird I'm answering my own question after I accepted a different answer, but...

I have a solution for that which can be applied only if you can inject switch to chrome which in my case is possible as I noted above:

> Important note: My extension isn't a public extension and it runs only on my browser so I can add any command line switch on start (in order to disable this limitation), if needed.

So the trick is to use the follwoing switch with your extension id:

```
--whitelisted-extension-id="abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"
```

Hope this will help someone someday.

Comment: This is working for me. If the extension is local to you, this can be used.

Answer (score -1):

The method that works is a user action invoking your extension (someone clicks something that tells Chrome it's okay because the user wanted it).

This temporarily grants "activeTab" permissions to the extension and is why it is working. (https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/activeTab)

To make it work like you intend (without an action bringing the activeTab permissions in automatically), you would need to declare it in your extension's permissions section, for example:

```
"permissions": [
  "tabs",
  "bookmarks",
  "http://www.blogger.com/",
  "http://*.google.com/",
  "unlimitedStorage",
  "activeTab"
],
```

see https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/declare_permissions

Comment: I added all possible permissions to the manifest file and it still doesn't allow me to run it without browse action.

Comment: Well the error message itself points to activeTab permissions not being set, and the links I showed says why it's working with one, but not the other. I'm trying to think of a way you can get your 2nd method to work; Instead of setTimeout, have you tried using https://developer.chrome.com/apps/alarms ?

Comment: Actually setTimeout was only given for example. It doesn't work from any triggering except a trigger which came from user.

Comment: well if the trigger comes from a user, then onClicked should automatically give you activeTab permission. Can you post the code as is instead of examples?

Comment: The trigger in my code is webSocket message. But I also tried it in onMessage event which received from inject js.

Comment: The error cites `activeTab` only as an example what "invoked" means, since its docs have it. So no, your method won't work. `"activeTab"` works the same way - it does nothing until user invokes.