# invoke active tab in code chrome extension for tab capture

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I would like to do tab capture by postmessage in chrome.

Below is the code that I have created.
The message will be sent by the content script.

Once the message is received, it will try to capture the current tab.

```js
chrome.runtime.onConnect.addListener(function(port){
    port.onMessage.addListener(function(message,sender){
        chrome.tabs.query({"active": true, "currentWindow": true}, function(tab) {
            chrome.tabCapture.capture(captureOptions, 
                function(stream) {
                    mediaRecorder = new MediaRecorder(stream, options);
                    if (stream && message.status == 'started') {

                        var options = {mimeType: "video/webm"};
                        
                        mediaRecorder.start();
                        mediaRecorder.ondataavailable = function(event) {
                            if (event.data.size > 0) {
                                recordedChunks.push(event.data);

                                var blob = new Blob(recordedChunks, {
                                    type: 'video/mp4'
                                });

                                var url = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
                                var a = document.createElement('a');
                                document.body.appendChild(a);
                                a.style = 'display: none';
                                a.href = url;
                                a.download = 'test.webm';
                                a.click();
                                window.URL.revokeObjectURL(url);
                                stream.getVideoTracks()[0].stop();
                            }
                        }
                        
                    }else if(message.status = "stopped"){
                        mediaRecorder.stop();
                    }
                }
            );
        });
    });
});
```

With the code above I am getting the Error

```js
Unchecked runtime.lastError while running tabCapture.capture: Extension has not been invoked for the current page (see activeTab permission). Chrome pages cannot be captured.
    at Object.callback (chrome-extension://haogilhkbanjpnkjbdgnefdgllfhldci/background.js:32:31)
```

Is there a way to bypass this?

Comment: Do you have a permission for "activeTab" in your manifest.json?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Capture chrome tab without browse action](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35985266/capture-chrome-tab-without-browse-action)